# Android application written with kotlin stops when launched

Tags: android, kotlin

My application written with koltin stops when launched. Knowing that I have no code error. Now, I can't even find the stacktrace to track errors and find out the problem.

Comment: Go through this link first. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either click on Alt+6
Or View > Windows tools > Logcat